# Using arithmetic within TikZ fill command to progressively change colour in for-loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I'd like to use a single variable in a for loop to control both the position of progressively plotted rectangles and their fill colour. This does not work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,x={(1cm,-0.2cm)},z={(0.5cm,0.5cm)}]
    \foreach \x in {0,0.2,...,1} \filldraw[fill=black!{100-100*\x},draw=black,thick] (\x,0,0) -- (\x,0,1) -- (\x,1,1) -- (\x,1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there any syntax that would allow me to perform simple arithmetic with a variable within the command input? I am quite used to doing things like that in e.g. MATLAB, so I was surprised that I couldn't find a simple solution.

I *can* do the reverse, and use a "clean" `\x` in the fill command while converting it into a useful scale for the point definition, but that seems inelegant since it would require me to do that four times.

Comment: Is this? `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,x={(1cm,-0.2cm)},z={(0.5cm,0.5cm)}]
\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \y using {100-100*\x}]
 in {0,0.2,...,1} 
\fill[black!\y,draw=black,thick] 
(\x,0,0) -- (\x,0,1) -- (\x,1,1) -- (\x,1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` see pgfmanual, 88
Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: That did it, thank you!

Comment: @BlackMild, please consider to expand your comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax for such computations inside a loop of TikZ, see [pgfmanual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), Section 88 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement

> /pgf/foreach/evaluate=⟨variable⟩ as ⟨macro⟩ using ⟨formula⟩

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,x={(1cm,-0.2cm)},z=0.5cm,0.5cm)}]
\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \y using {100-100*\x}] in {0,.2,...,1} 
\fill[black!\y,draw=black,thick] (\x,0,0)--(\x,0,1)--(\x,1,1)--(\x,1,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```